# python - checkbox in new window update fails and stays false

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import matplotlib
from tkinter import *
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import * 
import webbrowser
import subprocess
import csv
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from os import startfile
LARGE_FONT = ("Times", 11, "bold italic")
NORM_FONT = ("Helvetica", 9)
SMALL_FONT = ("Helvetica",7)
HELP_FONT=("Times", 9 , "bold")
class PAL3_guide(tk.Tk):

     def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

          tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
          container = tk.Frame(self)
          container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
          container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
          container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
          self.frames = {}

          for F in (StartPage,Tut01):

               frame = F(container, self)

               self.frames[F] = frame

               frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

          self.show_frame(StartPage)

     def show_frame(self, cont):
          frame=self.frames[cont]
          frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self,parent, controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, background="white")
          button_PAL = ttk.Button(self, text="Setup Guide", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Tut01))
          button_PAL.pack()

class Tut01(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self,parent,controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)       
          var=BooleanVar()
          label = tk.Label(self, text="Guide", font=LARGE_FONT)
          label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
          label = tk.Label(self, text="Check the methods to accomplish", font=NORM_FONT)
          label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
          c1 = Checkbutton(self, state=ACTIVE).pack()
          c1Label = tk.Label(self, text="digestion1",font=SMALL_FONT).pack()
          c2 = Checkbutton(self, state=ACTIVE).pack()
          c2Label = tk.Label(self, text="digestion2",font=SMALL_FONT).pack()
          c3 = Checkbutton(self, text="enrichment",state=ACTIVE, variable=var, command=lambda:onClick()).pack()

          def onClick():
               var.get()
               if var == True:
                    print("hi")
               else:
                    print("hiww")  
app = PAL3_guide()
app.geometry("1280x920")

app.mainloop()
```

Please check last code lines around the c3 checkbox.

I dont get why my boolean variable var is not getting updated by clicking the checkbox on the 2nd page. By clicking the checkbox (c3) the GUI should act differently. However as mentioned above it is not getting updated.. and stays False. I feel it keeps the value from start and does not get changed. Thanks for help ..

**EDIT:** 
Above the if statement missed the var.get() and I could make it work in smaller setup.. however, in the real tool I am calling a plt.figure() in the beginning since it included and anmiate function, If I erase this call, everything works like it should, might be that this figure calling forces the checkbutton to have the first onvalue ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would change `var`, to be `self.var` and set the off and on values explicitly:

- offvalue=
  The value corresponding to a non-checked button. The default is 0. (offValue/Value)
- onvalue=
  The value corresponding to a checked button. The default is 1. (onValue/Value)

  ```
  c3 = Checkbutton(self, text="enrichment",state=ACTIVE, 
                   variable=self.var, command=onClick,
                   onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
  c3.pack()
  ```

`command=` does not take a function call, just a function.

You would have to write either

```
command=lambda: print(self.var.get())
```

OR:

```
def printVar():
    print(self.var.get())
```

THEN:

```
..., command=printVar, ...
```

**NOTICE** the abscence of the paranthesis!

You are supposed to be settting `command` to a function.

When you use parenthesis, you *CALL* the function, you **DO NOT** want that here.

Comment: But sadly it appears that i cannot even set these variables, if i do simple like command=print(self.var.get()), onvalue=1, offvalue=0) It continues to print False (if self.var=BooleanVar().  It should be possible to run the code for you, maybe you could try it? Thx

Comment: no no, command= does not a function call, just a function. you would have to write either `command=lambda: print(self.var.get())` or define a function `printVar` that just does `print(self.var.get())` and then write `command=printVar` . NOTICE the abscence of the paranthesis! you are supposed to be settting it to a function. When you use parenthesis, you CALL the function, you DO NOT want that here

Comment: I will add the last comment to the answer for future reference ^^